# How do you layout a folder structure for beginner application

Tags: angular, angularjs, structure

How do you layout a folder structure for beginner application

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

put the layout component on seperate layout folder  and extend it on route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        loadChildren: () => import('./pages/pages.module').then(m => m.PagesModule)
      }
    ]
  },
```

on app component html

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

on some pages component say Home Component

```
.. some header
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>
..some footer
```

Comment: https://github.com/srijanlama/angular-test-ssr check basic boilerplate